# zsh: command not found: import

Tags: python, command-line, import, operating-system

I'm using MAC OS Catalina Version 10.15.1 and I'm working on a python project. Every time I use the command "import OS" on the command line Version 2.10 (433), I get this message: zsh: command not found: import. I looked up and followed many of the solutions listed for this problem but none of them have worked. The command worked prior to upgrading my MAC OS. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: This message is not coming from Python. Are you in zsh command line instead? Python command line is not the same as zsh command line.

Comment: my Echo $PATH is: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 2):

The file is being interpreted as zsh, not a python. I suggest you to add this to the first line:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: This is the comment I get after doing that:zsh: event not found: /usr/bin/env

Comment: try `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: That would be the message I would expect if you forget `#` (i.e. `!/usr/bin/env python` will search for `/usr/bin/env` event, `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of program is running `/usr/bin/env python <script>`.)

Comment: This only makes sense at the top of a file containing Python code. You still seem to be trying to write Python code at the `zsh` prompt. This is like trying to speak Chinese to a cab driver in Mexico City.

Answer (score -1):

Don't capitalize it.

`import os`

Comment: is lower case when I do it in the command line but I still get the same error

Comment: I didn't fully read the question. It seems like you're not in the Python command line but in zsh

Comment: I'm using zsh. That's what I need to use in order to execute the program I'm trying to run. This is the command I will need to input after "import os works": python find_sender.py message.eml

Comment: Okay so you're using shell and trying to run a program. Where does `import os` come in?

Comment: Normally prior to updating my computer I would have to first import sys; then add the path where the program is located sys.path.append('c:/python'); and then run the program using: python find_sender.py message.eml. The problem is that now I get the error message: zsh: command not found: import

Comment: Your memory is playing tricks on you. `import sys` and `sys.path.append` are Python commands, and can only be used inside Python program (such as `find_sender.py`) or Python console. `python find_sender.py` is a shell command, that can only be used in a system shell (such as `zsh`), and is used to start a Python program. Running the first two before the last one makes no sense, and can't work. Imagine trying to buy an apple before going to the supermarket. You can't buy apples at home, and you can't `import` before you start Python.